# List does not change in attempt to solve "Delete node in Doubly Linked List"

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am working on the GeeksForGeeks problem [Delete node in Doubly Linked List](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/delete-node-in-doubly-linked-list/1/):

> Given a doubly linked list and a position. The task is to delete a node from given position in a doubly linked list.
>
> #### Your Task:
>
> The task is to complete the function `deleteNode()` which should delete the node at given position and return the head of the linkedlist.

My code:

```
def deleteNode(self,head, x):
    # Code here
    temp=head        
    count_of_nodes=0
    prev_of_delete_node=None
    next_of_delete_node=None
    while temp != head:
        count_of_nodes+=1
        if count_of_nodes==x:
            prev_of_delete_node=temp.prev
            next_of_delete_node=temp.next
            #print(y.data,z.data)
            prev_of_delete_node.next=next_of_delete_node
            next_of_delete_node.prev=prev_of_delete_node
            break
        
        temp=temp.next
    
    if x==1:
        head=next_of_delete_node
```

There is no effect on the doubly LinkedList after executing above code. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- The `while` condition is wrong: it is false immediately, so the loop will not execute.
- The value for `prev_of_delete_node` could be `None` when you dereference it with `prev_of_delete_node.next`. So guard that operation. Same for `next_of_delete_node`.
- The function doesn't return anything, but it should return the head of the list after the deletion

Correction:

```
def deleteNode(self,head, x): 
    temp=head
    count_of_nodes=0
    prev_of_delete_node=None
    next_of_delete_node=None
    while temp:  # Corrected loop condition
        count_of_nodes+=1
        if count_of_nodes==x:
            prev_of_delete_node=temp.prev
            next_of_delete_node=temp.next
            if prev_of_delete_node:  # Guard
                prev_of_delete_node.next=next_of_delete_node
            if next_of_delete_node:  # Guard
                next_of_delete_node.prev=prev_of_delete_node
            break
        
        temp=temp.next
    # Should return:
    if x==1:
        return next_of_delete_node
    return head
```

Comment: Ooh Actually I was misunderstanding doubly LinkedList as Circular Doubly linkedList. That's why I used that while condition and no guard operations as circular linkedlist are connected. Thanks for clearing it.

Comment: Even with that understanding, the loop would not have executed. After you initialise `temp=head` the `while temp != head` condition is obviously false.

Comment: Yes You are totally right. It will terminate immediately.